# What rights do I need to run DBCC commands?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dbcc

Do I need to be sysadmin to run DBCC commands on SQL Server? Or is db_owner rights enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all of them are the same, but at least one explicitly requires **sysadmin**.

See the Permissions section of [DBCC INPUTBUFFER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187730.aspx) on msdn- this requires **sysadmin**. [DBCC CHECKDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx) only requires **db_owner**.

Are there any in particular that you're looking to use?

Comment: You can see all of the DBCC Commands for SQL 2008 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188796.aspx Each has a section on permissions.

Comment: I tried to run: DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE). From your link I can find that I need "view server state" permissions.

Comment: `MEMORYSTATUS` is not documented :-/